# Refraction BSDF shader showing as opaque for certain meshes and angles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection

This is a follow-up to the question I asked at [Muddled results from many-reflected mirror](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306569/muddled-results-from-many-reflected-mirror) which [Mr. A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/176864/mr-a) gave a great answer to.

I've extended the set of polyhedra that I'm rendering, and there are certain ones where the Refraction BSDF shader used as one input into a Mix Shader (the other input is a mirror) results in opaque faces.

[image: middle shape has opaque faces]

Here's a second view showing the same problem:

[image: second view of middle shape with opaque faces]

In the previously referenced post, the suggestion was to use a Refraction BSDF shader instead of a Transparent BSDF shader, and that in fact generally works better.  But it seems to cause this problem here.  If I swap the Transparent shader back in, it starts to work again - however, in general the rendering is not as good/accurate, so I don't want to go back to Transparent BSDF:

[image: with Transparent BSDF instead of Refraction BSDF]

Here is the `.blend` file here - note that the material in question is named `Two-Way Mirror Material`: https://bit.ly/bad-refraction-shading

Any ideas / suggestions here?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The normals on the object in the middle are flipped. If you recalculate them in _Edit Mode_ with `Shift`+`N` the shader works as expected. By the way, the normals are messed up on parts of the border/wireframe objects as well, it's not just as obvious since they don't use that refraction material.

Comment: Thats great, thanks very much @GordonBrinkmann.  The base meshes for these are generated through the "add_mesh_extra_objects" Blender addon.  I just put up a pull request that programmatically invokes normal correction when these objects are added to the scene.  Hopefully that will get accepted: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/pulls/105117